# How to make a textInput stretch an entire space dynamically without setting width - react native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native project. I currently have a bar that I made which has a text input and view selector. The view selector is small and the text nput is currently small. I dont want anything to change but I want the `textInput` to fill the empty white space between the input and the view selector dynamically.

here is the my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native'

import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons'

const SearchAndFilterComponent = () => {

  const [search, setSearch] = useState()

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.bar}> 
        <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
          <View style={styles.search}>
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            <View style={styles.searchIconContainer}>
              <Feather style={styles.searchIcon} name='search' color={'#273be2'} size={24} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.searchInputContainer}>
              <TextInput style={styles.searchInput} value={search} onChange={setSearch}  placeholder={'search'}/>
            </View>
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          </View>
          <View style={styles.navigationContainer}>
            <Feather name='navigation' color={'#273be2'} size={24} />
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
          <View style={styles.splitter}></View>
          <Feather style={styles.buttonIcon} name='map' color={'#273be2'} size={24} />
          <Text style={styles.text}>Map</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.bar}>
        <View style={styles.sorfAndFilter}>
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Feather name='filter' color={'#273be2'} size={24} />
            <Text style={styles.text}>Filter</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Feather name='sliders' color={'#273be2'} size={24} />
            <Text style={styles.text}>Sort</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Feather name='download' color={'#273be2'} size={24} />
          <Text style={styles.text}>Save</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.bar}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Results: "Palm Springs, CA"</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.text}>2,345 Properties</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: 50
  },
  bar: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  },
  searchContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  search: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  splitter: {
    height: 20,
    width: 2,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
    marginHorizontal: 8
  },
  mapContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  sorfAndFilter: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  searchInputContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'stretch'
  },
  searchInput: {
    fontSize: 17,
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderBottomColor: 'grey',
    alignItems: 'stretch'
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 17
  },
  buttonIcon: {
    marginRight: 4
  }
})

export default SearchAndFilterComponent
```

Here is an image:
[image: screen shot]

Comment: You may use `flex` in styles. See here [https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox.
Here is an example with tailwind css.

```
<View
    style={[
        tw`flex flex-row items-center mx-1 mb-1 rounded-full`,
        { backgroundColor: "#2E2E2E" },
    ]}
>
    <TextInput
        style={[
            tw`m-0 p-0 px-4 py-3 flex-grow text-white text-lg`,
            {},
        ]}
        placeholder="Type message here ..."
        placeholderTextColor="#777"
    />
    <Icon
        name="send"
        type="material"
        size={20}
        color="white"
        style={[
            tw`rounded-full p-3 mr-1`,
            { backgroundColor: "#B50055", opacity: 1 },
        ]}
    />
</View>
```

The idea is to use flexbox on the View and flex-grow on the TextInput.
The rest of the stuff will take the least space.